# How to i convert this bat file to install a game with it?

Tags: command-line, executable, batch

Bat file is following :

```
 @echo off
uharc x data.uha
call restore.bat
startw unpack.exe /nh
startw inject.exe "streams.wav"
startw regsetup.exe
del data.uha > nul
del uharc.exe > nul
del startw.exe > nul
del inject.exe > nul
del restore.bat > nul
echo -------------------------------------------
echo All Done. <<<---- GNdH ---->>> 
echo -------------------------------------------
```

So what I have to do to make it able to install this game? And any tips if possible?

I have tried stuff on it, I have got other bat files running like tekkit server bat. But I can't think of anything I could do on it. Is there any program other than wine/crossover that could run it?

When I use wine cmd it gives "application could not be started."

By renaming it to `.sh` I managed to get 5 or 6 sentences on it, but it still closes after half a second, like normally without changing anything.

Comment: What program  are you trying to install?

Comment: Hitman 2 Silent Assasin cracked version,(non topic(i bought Hitman 5 for ps3 3 days ago for ps3)

Answer (score 5):

You can't just "convert" this to a shell script, it calls other batch scripts, and exe files, which are Windows applications and not runnable under linux (or any other OS than windows for that matter).

The only way is to run it under Wine, which *emulates* a Windows environment.

Run the Wine windows console:

```
wineconsole cmd
```

And in this console, go to the path of the batch file and execute it:

```
cd path\to\batchfile
batchfile.bat
```

Comment: @user126336 Then you should set this answer as your [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask).